# What is a pythonic way to conditionally compose a sequence?

Tags: python

In Perl I can do something like this to dynamically create an array based on some conditions:

```
my @arr = (  
    $foo_defined ? 'foo' : (),    
    $bar_defined ? 'bar' : (),
    $baz_defined ? 'baz' : (),             
);
```

This creates an array of up to 3 elements based on the values of the variables. What would be the closest alternative to this in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A close literal translation might be

```
arr = list(chain(
    ['foo'] if foo_defined else [],
    ['bar'] if bar_defined else [],
    ['baz'] if baz_defined else [],
    ))
```

`a if b else c` is the Python equivalent of `b ? a : c`. `chain` concatenates multiple iterable values into a single sequence, similar to how `( (), (), () )` builds an array consisting of array elements (rather than nesting the arrays). `list` turns the `chain` object into an actual list.

The differing semantics of a Perl array and a Python list make it difficult to do exactly the same thing as tersely as Perl does. Python lacks the ability to have an expression evaluate to *nothing* to simulate the Perl array handling in your example. (Or put another way, `[ [], [], [] ]` in Python creates a list containing 3 empty lists, rather than a single empty list.)

---

[Patrick Artner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70144072/1126841) takes advantage of the fact that a list *comprehension* can selectively include values from one iterable into the list under construction.

A combination of his and my answers might look like

```
arr = [s for s in ['foo' if foo_defined else None,
                   'bar' if bar_defined else None,
                   'baz' if baz_defined else None] if s is not None]
```

The difference, though, is that a *full* list is built first, then a *second*, final list is built from the first one.

---

[Rolv Apneseth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70144030/1126841) dispenses with a single expression, building the result from an initially empty list and conditionally adding values to it one item at a time. It's terse, but the simulation of Perl-style statement modifiers isn't really idiomatic in Python. Instead, one would just use `if` statements:

```
arr = []
if foo_defined:
    arr.append("foo")
if bar_defined:
    arr.append("bar")
if baz_defined:
    arr.append("baz")
```

Comment: I'm not sure I even like my own answer, so I'm turning this into a comparison of the various approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Conditional list comprehension can do it:

```
defines = [True, False, True]
data =    ["foo", "bar", "baz"]


result = [d for defined,d in zip(defines,data) if defined]

print(result)
```

to get

```
['foo', 'baz']
```

`zip()` needs same-lenght lists - use [iterools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) if you need some more leeway or defaults.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly (I don't know any Perl I'm afraid), maybe something like this:

```
foo_defined = True
bar_defined = False
baz_defined = True


arr = []
foo_defined and arr.append("foo")
bar_defined and arr.append("bar")
baz_defined and arr.append("baz")
```

**Output**

```
>  print(arr)
['foo', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one more way:

```
arr = [
    *(['foo'] if foo_defined else ()),
    *(['bar'] if bar_defined else ()),
    *(['baz'] if baz_defined else ()),
    ]
```